# deploying in salesforce from Dev Org to Production Org

Tags: deployment, change-set

Can i create an outbound change set in a **developer organization** and deploy it to **production** ?
I have created my Project in my **developer edition** can i deploy it to **production** without using sandbox org is it possible or do i need sandbox edition to deploy my project to production ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not able to do this.

To deploy change set, you need to have connection between two orgs.

In this case, your Developer Edition will not have connection with Production Org.

**Deployment Connections**

> A deployment connection is required between two Salesforce orgs to
>   send change sets from one org to another. You can’t create deployment
>   connections between arbitrary orgs. Instead, you create connections
>   between all orgs affiliated with a production org. For example, if you
>   have a production org and two sandboxes, a deployment connection is
>   created between production and each sandbox. Also, a deployment
>   connection is created between the two sandboxes.

If you don't have connection between two org then you use a Force.com IDE to deploy metadata.

Comment: So do i need sandbox org first and then i will be able to deploy to production right @Devendra ?

Comment: You can use a Eclipse IDE to deploy metadata from Developer Edition to Production Org. to use a change set you need to have connection between two orgs. Generally, we have multiple developer Sandboxes from which we do the deployment to Prodution org.

Comment: @ALEX_RILEY Yes. Once you have sandbox you can create a connection between Production and related Sandbox Org. And, then can able to deploy changesets.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use a Change Set from a Developer Org to another org you would have to use a tool like the [Salesforce Deployment tool](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_tools_ant_using.htm&language=en_US) or one of the IDEs that support this.

Options are explained [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_tools_ant.htm&language=en_US) by Salesforce

Sandboxes are a separate type of Salesforce Org from the Developer environments which are on the test.salesforce.com url rather than salesforce.com.